# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null in JS

Tags: javascript, html, web

Code didn't work and still return 'f' world after function call, what's wrong with my code? thanks for help

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="changeText()">
    <p id="P1">
      fu
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
function changeText(){
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "slm"
}
```

Comment: Type: `P1 !== p1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this one, problem was that you can't call function `changeText()`:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function changeText(){
        document.getElementById("P1").innerHTML = "slm"
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="changeText()">
    <p id="P1">fu</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicklev/6puez7k5/)

Comment: fixed but why i cant?

Comment: @Hamidreza place your function in another file, or add to <head> tag, don't forget to upvote and check as answer please.

Comment: @Hamidreza and upvote please ( for other ho has similar questions ), huge thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Because the selector is case sensitive. Try to use P1 instead of p1: `document.getElementById("P1").innerHTML = "slm"`

Answer (score 2):

ID's in Javascript are case sensitive (all attributes are). The ID in the HTML is `P1` but you're looking for `p1` so it's not finding it.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the wrong ID Note P is capital letter, try:

```
document.getElementById("P1").innerHTML = "slm"
```